# Varios subprocesos a la vez

Tags: python, python-3.x

me gustaría descargar directos de YouTube, (varios a la vez) ejecuto mi codigo pero cuando comienza la descarga del primero nunca pasa al siguiente a no ser que cierre la consola manualmente, he probado de muchas formas pero siempre con el mismo resultado, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```
import time

from subprocess import call


def abrir_programas():
    call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Irus3d5f0E'], shell=False)

    time.sleep(15)

    call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwpkPf63304'], shell=False)



time.sleep(3)
abrir_programas()
```

Comment: pon cada uno en un hilo distinto

Comment: Es algo que nunca realice la verdad, ¿seria con "threading" no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde la versión 3.5+ de Python el modulo de `subprocess` tuvo una modificación en su API a través de la cual se agrego `subprocess.run` y se desplazó a funciones como `subprocess.call`, `subprocess.check_call`, `subprocess.check_output`, etc para posicionar a la función `subprocess.run` como la manera preferida de invocar subprocesos. Para casos de uso más avanzados a los proporcionados por `subprocess.run`, se hace uso de la interfaz subyacente que es `subprocess.Popen`.

Principalmente `subprocess.run` se usa cuando quieres ejecutar un comando y quieres esperar su finalización a través del mismo llamado. `subprocess.Popen` está en un nivel de abstracción más bajo y te permite hacer la invocación del comando, realizar otras cosas mientras este termina y después recolectar el resutaldo del comando a través de `subprocess.comunicate`.

**Nota.** Realmente el comando `subprocess.run` hace uso de `subprocess.Popen` internamente, para mayor información visita la documentación [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Un aspecto importante al intentar ejecutar subprocesos es que estos son procesos totalmente independientes del actual, en realidad, corren totalmente en paralelo con el proceso actual (considerando que el hardware lo permite) razon por la cual, crear un hilo (como en la solución planteada por  @Samuel82) no es realmente necesario o no ofrece ningún beneficio.

Dicho lo anterior, la solución más limpia para correr todos los procesos en paralelo a través de `subprocess.Popen` es:

```py
import subprocess

youtubedl_procs = []
urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Irus3d5f0E', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQTZN1fbSgg']

# Crea todos los subprocesos pero sin esperarlos
for url in urls:
    youtubedl_procs.append(subprocess.Popen(['youtube-dl', url]))

# Espera a cada uno de los procesos antes creados
for proc in youtubedl_procs:
    proc.communicate()
```

Este es un ejemplo sencillo, posiblemente quieras verificar que el proceso haya terminado de manera éxitosa verificando su [returncode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode).

Adicionalmente `youtube-dl` permite pasarle como argumentos varios urls, razón por la cual en un solo llamado podrías descargar todos los videos que quisieras. Muy posiblemente `youtube-dl` se encarge de descargarlos de manera eficiente (concurrente) por ti.

Comment: Me gusta mucho este método, Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

encontré una forma después del comentario de Chtistian , supongo hay formas mejores

```
import time
from subprocess import call
import threading

def descarga1():
    call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Irus3d5f0E'], shell=False)
    
def descarga2():
    call(['youtube-dl', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQTZN1fbSgg'], shell=False)

hilo1 = threading.Thread(target=descarga1)
hilo2 = threading.Thread(target=descarga2)

hilo1.start()
time.sleep(15)

hilo2.start()
time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: bueno, es una forma en la que lo haría

Comment: Esa es la forma, básicamente. Podrías lanzar todos los procesos a la vez; no tienes para que esperar.

Comment: La espera es para no forzar el CPU mas que nada